# Change background color with a loop onclick

Tags: javascript, loops, events, for-loop

here is my js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pYM38/16/

```
 var box = document.getElementById('box');

 var colors = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown', 'black'];

 box.onclick = function () {

    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {

        box.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];


      }

};
```

I'm in the process of learning JavaScript. I was trying to get this to loop through each color in the array, but when i click the box (demonstration on jsfiddle) it goes to the last element in the array.

Comment: It does loop through the array...and when it's finished it ends on the last one so `color = 'black'`. edit: i think loops happen faster then you think.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pYM38/17/

Comment: @JaredFarrish this is a stack. <3 Note: you must click multiple times for this to work.

Comment: @13ruce1337 - That can be interpreted multiple ways. `;)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish please post this as an answer. this is clear and simple. Luke no discredit, great answer as the question was unclear about what *he wanted* to do in the first place.

Comment: no prob, i like Jareds more too... i think i missunderstood the question...

Comment: thanks for the help guys. Jared's seems like the simplest. i tried luke's code, but nothing happened. i guess i need to read up on .push and .shift.

also misunderstood how loops work apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two methods, depending on what you're up to:

**Loop to Next on Click**

```
var box = document.getElementById('box'),
    colors = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown', 'black'];

box.onclick = function () {
    color = colors.shift();
    colors.push(color);

    box.style.backgroundColor = color;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYM38/17/

**Loop Through All on Click**

```
var box = document.getElementById('box'),
    colors = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown', 'black'];

box.onclick = function () {
    (function loop(){
        var color = colors.shift();

        box.style.backgroundColor = color;

        if (colors.length) {
            setTimeout(loop, 1000);
        }
    })();
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pYM38/23/

**Restarts on Next Click**

```
var box = document.getElementById('box'),
    colors = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown', 'black'];

box.onclick = function () {
    var set = colors.slice(0);

    (function loop(){
        var color = set.shift();

        box.style.backgroundColor = color;

        if (set.length) {
            setTimeout(loop, 1000);
        }
    })();
};
```

Comment: No problem. What I'm doing is I'm taking the first off the array (`array.shift()`), setting that as the color, and then "pushing" that color to the end. So it's like "give me the first, use it, then put it on the end". Note that `array.pop()` differs from `array.shift()` in that it will give you the last item; `array.unshift()` will put the item at the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 2):

you want it to be animated, or delayed?

Because your example works perfectly, you are looping through all colors and it is so fast that you see only the last one.

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');

 var colors = ['purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown', 'black'];
 var running = 0;    
 box.onclick = function () {
    if(running>0) return;
    for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        running++;
        setTimeout(function() {
             box.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
             running--;
        }, 1000);

      }

};
```

Comment: This is a true loop, as opposed to just naming your function loop like the previous answer. The first answer gets the job done, but I think you really answered the op question and my own. tysm!